# Django, How to get user sign up statistics?

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth, usage-statistics

I have a Django project that is using allauth to handle user logins and signups.

All I am trying to do is have a way to view the sign-up stats.  It would be nice to see how many user sign-ups there were today vs yesterday and so forth.  I do not need any fancy graphs or reports, just numbers.

I have done quite a lot of research on this and haven't seen a clean cut solution. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Before posting, you are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you have a *specific* coding question, include a summary of what you have tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [facebook analytics](https://developers.facebook.com/products/analytics/quickstarts/web/), include this snippet of code after opening the body tag:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then, when you have a suitable amount of data you can start seeing all about your facebook app (login, shares, reach, etc) in  [fb analytics dashboard](https://www.facebook.com/analytics/)